# Wordpress redirect specific link to custom link

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I have a wordpress website and I want to redirect a specific link to my custom link. I do not want to use any plugin and want to achieve this by writing code in functions.php file. The code that I tried is writen below

```
function custom_redirect() {
    if(is_page(7)) {
        wp_redirect('http://example.com/my-account/orders/', 301);
        exit();
    }
}
add_action ('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
```

Now the page, ( `(is_page(7))` ), from which I want to redirect the users has the url which is http://www.example.com/my-account/ and I want to redirect them to http://www.example.com/my-account/orders. I tried the `site_url('/my-account/')` function also but unable to achieve that.

Comment: What's the point of using is_page(7), is this the same page as my-account ?

Comment: Yes. `is_page(7)` is' example.com/my-account' and I want to redirect to 'example.com/my-account/orders'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you test for `is_page('my-account')` it will return true even when you are viewing an WooCommerce account endpoint.  The workaround is to check the global $wp variable for the requested page slug.

```
function custom_redirect() {
    global $wp;

    if( $wp->request == 'my-account' ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( 'my-account/orders/' ) );
        exit;
    }
}

add_action ('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure that i understood, but i propose this:

```
function custom_redirect() {
    if(is_page(7)) {
        header('Location: http://example.com/my-account/orders/');
        exit();
    }
}
add_action ('template_redirect', 'custom_redirect');
```

Comment: Use the inbuilt WordPress functions for redirecting.